# Payeezy “payment method is missing”

Tags: php, api, payment

my Payeezy is throwing an error “payment method is missing”

im testing authorize transaction which i believe doesnt require payment method.

here’s my code

http://pastebin.com/gEyAfyuf

here’s the response on our site at http://wolcottschoolpay.com/test/payeezy_php/test.php

```
{
correlation_id: "228.1440254919101",
Error: 
{
messages: 
[
{
code: "payment_method_missing",
description: "The payment method is missing"
},
{
code: "missing_amount",
description: "The amount is missing"
},
{
code: "missing_currency",
description: "The currency is missing"
}
]
},
transaction_status: "Not Processed",
validation_status: "failed",
transaction_type: "authorize",
currency: "USD”
}
```

I copied most of the part here on the official payeezy php direct library on github.

authorize transaction is on line 127
https://github.com/payeezy/payeezy_direct_API/blob/master/payeezy_php/example/tests/PayeezyTest.php

i also tried both my merchant test details and the one provided at payeezy library but none worked.

Is this a library issue? any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add x_currency_code and x_amount in api request. without amount and currency it can not process transaction.

And to process payment you need to select payment method like VISA, AMERICAN EXPRESS, DISCOER etc...

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, your request JSON payload is missing amount, currency and payment method. Please add those and try again.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Im testing authorize request which i believe doesnt require amount/currency and payment method.

Comment: here's their unit testing regarding authorize request.    

 `public function testGetToken()
    {
        $primaryTxResponse_JSON = json_decode(self::$payeezy->authorize($this->setTokenPayload()));
        $this->assertEquals($primaryTxResponse_JSON->transaction_status,"approved");
    }`

you can see the full code at line 127
https://github.com/payeezy/payeezy_direct_API/blob/master/payeezy_php/example/tests/PayeezyTest.php

Comment: The sample code you are using is for getToken - 
https://developer.payeezy.com/tokenizedtreditcardpost/apis/post/transactions/tokens-1



For authorize, you need to be sending the payload as shown here: 
https://developer.payeezy.com/tokenbasedpayments/apis/post/transactions